# How can I pass data from a meteor controller to a meteor helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, controller, helper

I am trying to pass data from a controller to a helper:

My controller:

```
exampleController = RouteController.extend({

data: function() {

    var a = 13;
    return {
        info: a
    }
},

action: function() {
    this.render('samplePage');
}

});
```

My helper:

```
Sample.helpers({
    console.log(info)
});
```

However, I keep getting a 'undefined' error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a data context means that your `this` is set to whatever you data context is. To access your data context, you would use `this` or `this.something` both in your template and in your helpers.

On a side note, your helper method syntax is off. According to [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers), you should be using

```
Template.sometemplate.helpers({
  somehelper: function(){
    console.log(this.a);
  }
})
```